# backbutton on my android webview crash

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, android-webview, back-button

Now im having trouble getting the hardware back button to work. The app loads fine as does page and everything else but as soon as i hit the phones back button it crashes then forces close.  Google's instructions sucked also as i am a beginner and they presume you know a certain amount.

Please advise where i should place the code if it is in the wrong place and also if there is anything wrong with it itself.

Cheers!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity

    {

        final Activity activity = this;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                {
                    activity.setTitle("Učitavanje...");
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                    if(progress == 100)
                        activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            });

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
                {
                    try {
                        webView.stopLoading();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        webView.clearView();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/greska/greska.html");
                    super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl("http://mobile.myweb.rs");

        }
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
        { 
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        WebView webView;
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed (){

            if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();       
            }
            else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    finish();
            }
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `super.onBackPressed` AND `finish()`. Use just one of them.

EDITED: Write

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

instead of

```
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Then declare

```
    WebView webView
```

before your activity onCreate method.

You're getting crach beacause you're trying to use a WebView variable which is actually null.